# How to measure interference using power measurements?

Tags: wireless-networking, interference

We are doing a project on interference mitigation in co-working WLANs. For the task of in cooperating interference we need to model interference in an indoor environment. How can we achieve this task using power signal power measurements. Is applying SINR correct ? If so how can we deal with Adjacent channel interference in that case?

Comment: Have a little Read on [MetaGeek](http://www.metageek.com/training/resources/adjacent-channel-congestion.html) If you need any more information let me know. You need to model the interference from what im gathering from your post.

Comment: Thanks i read on Metageek. The problem is that we already used a path loss model to predict the power level in an indoor environment. But now we need to consider interference as well. (mainly co-channel ) interference. The purpose of this study is to find the optimal location for an AP in an indoor environment. You have any idea on this ???

Comment: Was going to leave you a nice answer but im slammed at work at the moment. [Read Here](http://www.ekahau.com/wifidesign/blog/2015/07/10/ekahau-site-survey-heatmap-visualizations-part-7-channel-overlap/?more=2448) Im pretty sure this will  give you an idea about setting up the APs with minimum to no interference.

Comment: sorry for being late to reply. I'll read it. Thanks a lot.